# pyqt changing the color of a button when pressed using a stylesheet

Tags: button, colors, pyqt, stylesheet

i am trying to change the color of a button when is press,  and look like it can be done directly with in the stylesheet with out to do a function and then connect it.

in 
http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples/
show this example:

```
QPushButton#evilButton {
    background-color: red;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: beige;
    font: bold 14px;
    min-width: 10em;
    padding: 6px;
}
QPushButton#evilButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(224, 0, 0);
    border-style: inset;
}
```

how can translate that to python pyqt?

Answer (score 11):

i was able to make it work like this, that way the color button is blue and when is press changes to red

```
    btn_text = QString("this font color")
    btn = QPushButton(btn_text)

    btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: blue }"
                      "QPushButton:pressed { background-color: red }" )
```

Answer (score 6):

No translation needed, it is a stylesheet: a text document used by qt (and therefore by pyqt, since pyqt calls qt). For example:

```
self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("""
       QGroupBox 
       { 
           background-color: rgb(255, 255,255); 
           border:1px solid rgb(255, 170, 255); 
       }
       """
)
```

Take a look at http://vimeo.com/50033293.

Comment: On SO you thank via upvote, and also let others know which answer was most useful by accept, if not useful put comment in case person can edit

Answer (score 3):

```
self.button.setStyleSheet('background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;')    

nameofbutton.setStyleSheet('background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;')
```